# Using archive-tar-minitar with jRuby

Tags: ruby, jruby, archive, tar

RubyGems is included in (a part of) in jRuby 1.7.4 ( jruby.org ) and archive-tar-minitar is 'in' RubyGems.
Isn't it??
http://rubygems.org/gems/archive-tar-minitar

So why I cannot run this example: http://rubydoc.info/gems/archive-tar-minitar/0.5.2/frames

```
require 'zlib'
require 'archive/tar/minitar'
include Archive::Tar

  # Packs everything that matches Find.find('tests')
File.open('test.tar', 'wb') { |tar| Minitar.pack('tests', tar) }
  # Unpacks 'test.tar' to 'x', creating 'x' if necessary.
Minitar.unpack('test.tar', 'x')
```

I got the error:

```
LoadError: no such file to load -- archive/tar/minitar
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1054
  require at C:/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:51
   (root) at EssRB.rb:23
```

I guess I have first to install archive-tar-minitar
Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 0):

```
SOLVED after installing: gem install archive-tar-minitar CONFIG: MS Windows 7 SP1, JRuby 1.7.4.
```

Ruby Gems must be installed before they can be used. This is why the error occurred in the first place. For more information, visit the http://www.rubygems.org web site.